# Manage XML strings with sed

Tags: xml, shell, sed

Hi i'm trying to make some replacements in an XML file using sed, but i think i'm missing something...

The kind of string i'm trying to replace is the follow:

```
<Field name="ColName" type="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[EXTRACT_DATE]]></Field>
```

I store it in a variable

```
F_LEFTSTR="<Field name=\"ColName\" type=\"java\.lang\.String\"><!\[CDATA\["
F_RIGHTSTR="\]\]><\/Field>"
F_RIGHTSTR="<\/Field>"
F_STRTOFIND="$F_LEFTSTR$FLD$F_RIGHTSTR"
```

and i try to manage special characters using backslash \

```
sed -i "s/$F_STRTOFIND/REPLACEMENT/" XML.xml
```

Comment: Use an XML-aware tool to modify XML.

Comment: It's a dynamic change, reading data from another file, there is a tool that can to this?

Comment: There are many. I know (and maintain) [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), but there are several other tools, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes in the bash command prevent interpolation of shell variables.  You'll have to use double quotes and escape the embedded double quotes.